# Howto insert a row in CKAN Data store in PHP

Tags: php, ckan

What is the best way to insert a new row in a CKAN data store from a PHP program?

Can the dataset in the data store be created on the fly?

Please provide a code snipped as example.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't know PHP so I can't answer this, but in case anyone wants to try making a PHP code snippet - Yes, it is possible to create a dataset, then a resource, then a datastore table using the API. The two sections of the docs you'll need are: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#the-datastore-api and http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html.